# Send email correct trigger setup

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like some help setting up a trigger... I got a a sheet connected to a form that gets a survey, but in a different tab I pull the data just from 2 specific users and I tried to set up a trigger that sends an email when this 2 users submit the form.

I already tried: From spreadsheet (On change, On Edit and On form submit) but nothing...  I don't want to setup Time-Driven or from calendar because or they are going to receive the same email a lot of times or if they submit one after the other only the last will receive the email.

The script is the following:

```
function SendEmail() {
  var Spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var Sheet = Spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Email test");
  var counter = Sheet.getRange("AB1").getValue();
  var email = ""+ Sheet.getRange(counter, 25).getValue();
  Logger.log(email);
  var Subject = "Summary Of Your Coaching Session";
  var Session = Sheet.getRange(counter, 15).getValue();
  var KPI = Sheet.getRange(counter, 9).getValue();
  var exception = Sheet.getRange(counter, 6).getValue();
  var casenum = Sheet.getRange(counter, 8).getValue();
  var wins = Sheet.getRange(counter, 10).getValue();
  var coachwins = Sheet.getRange(counter, 11).getValue();
  var timeframe = Sheet.getRange(counter, 14).getValue();
  var smartplan = Sheet.getRange(counter, 18).getValue();
  var nickname = Sheet.getRange(counter, 27).getValue();
  var evenbetter = Sheet.getRange(counter, 16).getValue();

  var type = Sheet.getRange(counter, 26).getValue();
  Logger.log(type);

  if (type == 'Win'){

    var body = ('Hello '+ nickname +','+'<br><br>Here is the summary of your '+ Session +':'+'<br><br>Your coaching was based on <b>'+ KPI +'</b> and case number '+ casenum +' and we identified the following wins '+ wins +', '+ coachwins +' and we are committed to '+ smartplan +' that we will be following on ' + timeframe +'.<br><br>');

  } else if (type == "Full"){

    var body = ('Hello '+ nickname +','+'<br><br>Here is the summary of your '+ Session +':'+'<br><br>Your coaching was based on <b>'+ KPI +'</b>, from case number '+ casenum +' and the skill that we are focusing on mastering is '+ evenbetter +'. We are committing to "'+ smartplan +'" that we will be following on ' + timeframe +'.<br><br>');

  } else if (type == "Exception"){

    var body = ('Hello '+ nickname +','+'<br><br> A Coaching for Excellence exception has been submitted due to <b>'+ exception +'</b>, so we will meet next week. Your development is highly important for us, we encourage you to keep on working on your previous action plan. <br><br> If you have any questions regarding your previous action plan contact me.<br><br><br><br>');

  }

  MailApp.sendEmail(email, Subject, body, {htmlBody : body, noReply : true})

}
```

Comment: You should be using an "on form submit" trigger and use the [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49773518/send-email-based-on-the-sum-of-cells-from-a-form-submission-in-google-sheets/49774861#49774861) as an example.

Comment: As i stated, I already used "On form submit" and nothing happened (I don't know if it is because the sheet is not the form recipient one, but still is on the same spreadsheet)

Comment: Did you install the "on form submit" trigger? Did you see that it wasn't running? Or did you only see that you weren't getting the desired output?

Comment: Yes I did (no the script you have but the Trigger shows:

Run: SendEmail 
Event: From spreadsheet - On form submit (also used On edit and On change)

Comment: Did the trigger work? Specifically, I'm asking if it "triggered", not asking if your function worked.

Comment: I reseted the trigger and now it works... My only problem is that it sends the last email on each form submission... :facepalm:

Answer (score 1):

You should be using an "on form response" trigger, and then use the [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit) provided by that trigger. The event object provides all of the form response data that you need. If you need to access information that was not submitted in the form, but is on the same row as the form data, then you can use `formResponse.range.getRow()` to get the row number.

This is what your code might look like with proper usage of the event object:

```
function SendEmail(formResponse) {
  var email = formResponse.values[24];
  Logger.log(email);
  var subject = "Summary Of Your Coaching Session";
  var session = formResponse.values[14];
  var kpi = formResponse.values[9];
  var exception = formResponse.values[5];
  var casenum = formResponse.values[7];
  var wins = formResponse.values[9];
  var coachwins = formResponse.values[10];
  var timeframe = formResponse.values[13];
  var smartplan = formResponse.values[17];
  var nickname = formResponse.values[26];
  var evenbetter = formResponse.values[15];
  var type = formResponse.values[25];
  Logger.log(type);
  if (type == 'Win'){
    var body = ('Hello '+ nickname +','+'<br><br>Here is the summary of your '+ session +
                ':'+'<br><br>Your coaching was based on <b>'+ kpi +'</b> and case number '+
                casenum +' and we identified the following wins '+ wins +', '+ coachwins +
                ' and we are committed to '+ smartplan +' that we will be following on ' +
                timeframe +'.<br><br>');
  } else if (type == "Full") {
    var body = ('Hello '+ nickname +','+'<br><br>Here is the summary of your '+ session +
                ':'+'<br><br>Your coaching was based on <b>'+ kpi +'</b>, from case number '+
                casenum +' and the skill that we are focusing on mastering is '+ evenbetter +
                '. We are committing to "'+ smartplan +'" that we will be following on ' +
                timeframe +'.<br><br>');
  } else if (type == "Exception"){
    var body = ('Hello '+ nickname +','+'<br><br> A Coaching for Excellence exception has been submitted due to <b>'+
                exception +'</b>, so we will meet next week. Your development is highly important for us, we encourage '+
                'you to keep on working on your previous action plan. <br><br> If you have any questions regarding your '+
                'previous action plan contact me.<br><br><br><br>');
  }
  MailApp.sendEmail(email, Subject, body, {htmlBody : body, noReply : true})
}
```

Comment: But with this it will get it from the Form Response sheet and what Im doing is that of 15 people that enter data in there, I need to the the data just of 2 and send an email to verify the information that they submited...

So in the next tab of the FormResponses I collect only the data of this 2 guys and with a VLOOKUP I search for the email address to mail the verification.